# Empty slice returned

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Fairly new at go. 
I am trying to basically read all the files in directory and subdirectory, populate in a slice and then process further. 
Here is the code (Main functions to look are **Main and expandDirectory**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

const dirname string = "MyDirectory"

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

}

func expandDirectory(currentDirectory string, allFiles []os.FileInfo) []os.FileInfo {
    files, e := ioutil.ReadDir(currentDirectory)
    check(e)
    for _, internalDir := range files {
        switch mode := internalDir.Mode(); {
        case mode.IsDir():
            var filepath = currentDirectory + internalDir.Name() + "\\"
            expandDirectory(filepath, allFiles)
        case mode.IsRegular():
            allFiles = append(allFiles, internalDir)
        }
    }
    return allFiles
}

func main() {
    allFiles := expandDirectory(dirname, make([]os.FileInfo, 5))
    fmt.Printf("%v", cap(allFiles))
}
```

The final print will print 5 which is the initial value.

Just FYI, the expandDirectory function is just recursive function in case of directories and adding the file reference in case of a file.

Thanks for the help

Where am I going wrong

**FINAL CODE (changes Only)**

```
func main() {
  allFiles := expandDirectory(dirname)
}


func expandDirectory(currentDirectory string) []os.FileInfo {
    allFiles := make([]os.FileInfo, 0, 5)
    ....
        case mode.IsDir():
    ....
            allFiles = append(allFiles, expandDirectory(filepath)...)
    ....
    return allFiles
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the result to it:

```
allFiles = append(allFiles, expandDirectory(filepath, allFiles)...)
```

Also

```
 allFiles := expandDirectory(dirname, make([]os.FileInfo, 5))
```

should be:

```
 allFiles := expandDirectory(dirname, make([]os.FileInfo, 0, 5))
```

Otherwise you will be appending to allFiles and the first 5 items will be empty.